# How to do toggle two mutually exclusive radio buttons in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have two radio buttons. When I click on one, the other should become unchecked, and vice versa.

The code I've produced so far is not working:

```
<input type="radio" id="rbdemail" onclick="chekrbdclick()" checked="checked" />
<input type="radio" id="rbdsitelnk" onclick="chekrbdclick()" />

function chekrbdclick() 
{
  // How to manage here?
}
```

Comment: Use same name to both radio buttons, there's no need of using JavaScript

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple, just use a 'name' property with the same value for both elements:

```html
<html>
<body>

<form>
  <input type="radio" name="size" value="small" checked> Small
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="size" value="large"> Large
</form> 

</body>
</html>
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

```html
<form>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="size" value="small" checked> Small
  </label>
  <br>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="size" value="large"> Large
  </label>
</form>
```

Give them a `name` attribute with common `value` like **size**, and it will work. For best practice, you can place your `input` tag inside a `label` tag, so that, even if your user clicks on the text beside the button (ie on "Small" or "Large"), the respective `radio button` gets selected.

Answer (score -1):

The perfect answer is above answered ,but I wanna share you how it can work by javascript ,this is javascript work (not standard answer) ....

```
    <input type="radio" id="rbdemail" onclick="chekrbdclick(0)" checked="checked" value="Small" />Small<br>
    <input type="radio" id="rbdsitelnk" onclick="chekrbdclick(1)" value="Large" />Large
    <script>
    function chekrbdclick(n) 
    {
      var small = document.getElementById('rbdemail');
      var large = document.getElementById('rbdsitelnk');
     if(n === 0){  
      small.checked = true;  
      large.checked = false;
     }
     else {   
      small.checked = false;  
      large.checked = true;
     }
    }
    </script>
```